# How to enable custom URLs in Google Chrome?

Tags: browser, google-chrome, dns, http-status-code-404

for local development I'm running a local webserver with virtual hosts to manage multiple webprojects requiring their own URL. Normally I use URLs like myproject.com.local and the real project will be located at myproject.com. Everything works fine in Safari, IE or Firefox. But Google Chrome throws a 404. As far as I know they have some kind of intelligent address bar. Is there any possibility to get it working with all domains?

Best Regards,
Bernd

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be working with all domains, as long as your workstations **DNS** can resolve the name to an ip-address. Also, check if you have any **proxy settings** in Chrome, sometimes it helps to check the 'Bypass proxy for local domains'-checkbox (somewhere in the settings).

Also make sure that when you request non-standard domains or port-numbers to put **http://** in front of your url.

Good luck.

Comment: I checked on my friend laptop but he have linux so when you're offline completely, chrome doesn't work on local domains, shows error 404 =)) Don't know about windows.